# how to use ngRepeat and ngShow/ngIf together in meanJS-AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, meanjs

Im trying to use ngRepeat with ngIf or ngShow together. It just wont work.. Im trying to display only the ones that matches "poster" and "viewer" id so the user will only see his/her own posts. Im using meanJS. Im looking into directives, because i dont know if thats what im missing.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3 extraSpaceList text-center" data-ng-repeat="motor in motorsCtrl.motors | filter:searchText | filter:searchFilter">
        <div ng-if="((authentication.user) && (authentication.user._id == motor.user._id))">
        <a class="list-group-item" ng-click="motorsCtrl.modalUpdate('lg', motor)">
            <div class="bg-info">
                <h4 class="list-group-item-heading" data-ng-bind="motor.title"></h4>
            </div>
        </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: do you have a code snippet on jsbin or jsfiddle, etc?

Comment: it hasnt been uploaded to any site like that, I thought I new to learn a bit more before that

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to look into.

First:

If you are using `ng-if`, `ng-if` will create its own scope. You cannot access the parent scope model from within `ng-if` unless you use the `$parent` service. So you will need to change your models: `motorsCtrl.modalUpdate('lg', motor)` becomes `$parent.modalUpdate('lg', motor)` and `motor.title` becomes `$parent.motor.title`

Second:

You should probably start out using `ng-show` instead of `ng-if` here. At least until your app renders a view. But look into it.

You may want to consider the following (taken from @markovuksanovic):

`ng-if` will remove elements from DOM. This means that all your handlers or anything else attached to those elements will be lost. For example, if you bound a click handler to one of child elements, when `ng-if` evaluates to false, that element will be removed from DOM and your click handler will not work any more, **even after `ng-if` later evaluates to true and displays the element.** You will need to reattach the handler. 
ng-show/ng-hide does not remove the elements from DOM. It uses CSS styles to hide/show elements (note: you might need to add your own classes). This way your handlers that were attached to children will not be lost.
`ng-if` creates a child scope while ng-show/ng-hide does not

Comment: That might be useful, but here we are talking about sensitive info. Might not be a good idea to show sensitive info to everyone and just hide it in css? Am I right about this?? Pls confirm. What Im trying to do is ng-repeat will show all posts but that ng-if auth(see it in the code on top) will reduce this to only those that has been posted by that specific user, i dont want to let him edit anyone else`s posts. Pls correct me!!

Comment: Unfortunately the problem is a lot bigger... the main oroblem is that im a beginner and i do NOT understand what im doing. I cant even get it running. My question would be if finally i get it running, would it be safe? Can someone easily hack it? That page meant to display  "your own" posts so you can edit them. I dont want to let users edit or delete other user`s posts. I uploaded a few things. index2.html is where you can see all posts and index.html meant to be only for your own posts. [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RoGOxchWVyCFST6ceJAu)

Comment: can i add a "condition" to ng repeat? like`((authentication.user) && (authentication.user._id == motor.user._id))`

Comment: I thnk best would be to only use ngRepeat with that condition. Still dunno how.. I started angular tutorial from beginning, my knowledge it not good enough yet

Comment: Follow these steps to make sure your app works right. 1) Remove ng-if or ng-show. Check if the page renders ok. You will then know if ng-if or ng-show causing the problem or something else. 2)If step 1 renders the page correctly, use ng-if="true" or ng-show="true". It should not work because of scope issue. Change scope using $parent.'whatever'...check my last comment. App may still not work because ng-if removes models/event handlers. Try with ng-show. 3)Use ng-show=(...one condition only - which is (authentication.user). See if everything works ok. Next try both conditions.

Comment: If you are just beginning, first try to make your app work (use ng-show ). Then try to improve security with ng-if.